# Javascript: How to remove an array item(JSON object) based on the item property value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

like this:

```
var arr = [  
            { name: "robin", age: 19 },   
            { name: "tom", age: 29 },  
            { name: "test", age: 39 } 
          ];
```

I want to remove array item like this(an array prototype method):

```
arr.remove("name", "test");  // remove by name  
arr.remove("age", "29");  // remove by age
```

currently, I do it by this method(use jQuery):

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(name, value) {  
    array = this;  
    var rest = $.grep(this, function(item){    
        return (item[name] != value);    
    });  

    array.length = rest.length;  
    $.each(rest, function(n, obj) {  
        array[n] = obj;  
    });  
};
```

but I think the solution has some performance issue,so any good idea?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would hope jQuery's oddly-named `grep` would be reasonably performant and use the built-in `filter` method of Array objects where available, so that bit is likely to be fine. The bit I'd change is the bit to copy the filtered items back into the original array:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(name, value) {  
    var rest = $.grep(this, function(item){    
        return (item[name] !== value); // <- You may or may not want strict equality
    });

    this.length = 0;
    this.push.apply(this, rest);
    return this; // <- This seems like a jQuery-ish thing to do but is optional
};
```