# Concat JSON array objects without index 0 undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is a basic question but I'm just curious about an elegant way to do something (I already have solution for *dirty way*). I have the code below to start with empty var `a` as JSON array. Then I want to `concat` more JSON objects array into it later on:

```
var a = [{}];
a = a.concat([{"a":"b1"},{"a":"b2"}]);
a.splice(0,1); // This does not work to remove index 0 of undefined
console.log(a[0].a + " " + a[1].a + " " + a[2].a);
```

The problem is when `a` declared, it already came with `undefined` in **index 0**. I could **re-generate** the whole array to remove all `undefined` using `push.apply()` but that seems unnecessary overhead. See:

[Javascript: How to remove an array item(JSON object) based on the item property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879447/javascript-how-to-remove-an-array-itemjson-object-based-on-the-item-property)

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to `concat` arrays but override the **index 0** on initial `concat`?
2. OR is there a way to use `concat` without declaring it `a = [{}]`?

Comment: Why don't you use `a = []`?

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "JSON array" in JavaScript. It's just an array.

Comment: Also your array "a" does **not** have `undefined` in index 0; it has an empty object.  If you declare the array with just `[]`, then it will have a length of 0.

Comment: Are you aware your error comes from `a[2].a` at the console.log line? At that point, there's not `a[2]`. Before the console.log call, there's no error.

Comment: Ops! Dumb mistake on my end. Thanks guy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be declaring it as an empty array, there is no need for the empty object inside.

```
var a = [];
```

Output in a console

```
> var a = [];
  undefined
> a = a.concat([{"a":"b1"},{"a":"b2"}]);
  [Object, Object]
```